# How to access the next sibling of the custom element from within the class?

Tags: javascript, dom, web-component, html5-template

In web components, I have a custom element, and I want to access the next sibling. How can I do that? I have this

```
class DomElement extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        let shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
        const t = document.currentScript.ownerDocument.querySelector('#x-foo-from-template');
        const instance = t.content.cloneNode(true);
        shadowRoot.appendChild(instance);
    }

    fixContentTop() {
        var sibling = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (sibling) {

        }
    }
}
```

but `sibling` becomes null.

Des anyone know how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Well, are you sure it *has* a next element sibling? Please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] demonstrating the problem, using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button).

Answer (score 1):

Actually it works when in the method that call `this.nextElementSibling`, `this` really represents the custom element who has a sibling.

It work in this example because, thanks to the arrow function, this refers to the custom element:

```js
customElements.define('dom-elem', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()
    var sh = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'})
    sh.appendChild(document.querySelector('template').content.cloneNode(true))
    sh.querySelector('button').onclick = () =>
      console.log('sibling = %s', this.nextElementSibling.localName)
  }
})
```

```html
<dom-elem></dom-elem>
<dom-elem></dom-elem>
<template>
  <button>Get Sibling</button>
</template>
```

If you use the `function ()` syntax, this will refers to `<button>` and therefore won't return any sibling element:

```js
customElements.define('dom-elem', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()
    var sh = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'})
    sh.appendChild(document.querySelector('template').content.cloneNode(true))
    sh.querySelector('button').onclick = function () {
      console.log('sibling = %s', this.nextElementSibling)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<dom-elem></dom-elem>
<dom-elem></dom-elem>
<template>
  <button>Get Sibling</button>
</template>
```